# access issue when using Azure Service principal created in a new tenant

Tags: azure-active-directory, terraform-provider-azure, azure-service-principal

I have the following situation.

1. Have an account from my workplace and a Visual Studio Professional subscription.
2. I cannot create service principals in my organization tenant. It is forbidden and I will not be given privileges to do that.
3. I create a new tenant by myself, say "myowntenant". Created a new app and by the virtue of this, I got a service principal named "example-app"
4. I then went to the Visual studio subscription and gave the service principal(example-app) Contributor access to the subscription.

When I am trying to use my terraform environment using the VS subscription id, myowntenant ID, client id and secret of "example-app", I get unauthorized error stating the access token is from the wrong issuer.

Looks like my understanding about the Azure subscriptions, tenant and service principal is incorrect. Can someone tell me why this wont work even though the service principal has contributor access in the subscription?

Code for terraform:

```
## <https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/index.html>
provider "azurerm" {
  version = "=2.5.0"
  features {}
}

## <https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/resource_group.html>
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "rg" {
  name     = "TerraformTesting"
  location = "eastus"
}

## <https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/availability_set.html>
resource "azurerm_availability_set" "DemoAset" {
  name                = "example-aset"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
}

## <https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/virtual_network.html>
resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "vnet" {
  name                = "vNet"
  address_space       = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
}

## <https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/subnet.html> 
resource "azurerm_subnet" "subnet" {
  name                 = "internal"
  resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.vnet.name
  address_prefix       = "10.0.2.0/24"
}

## <https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/network_interface.html>
resource "azurerm_network_interface" "example" {
  name                = "example-nic"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name

  ip_configuration {
    name                          = "internal"
    subnet_id                     = azurerm_subnet.subnet.id
    private_ip_address_allocation = "Dynamic"
  }
}

## <https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/windows_virtual_machine.html>
resource "azurerm_windows_virtual_machine" "example" {
  name                = "example-machine"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  size                = "Standard_F2"
  admin_username      = "adminuser"
  admin_password      = "P@$$w0rd1234!"
  availability_set_id = azurerm_availability_set.DemoAset.id
  network_interface_ids = [
    azurerm_network_interface.example.id,
  ]

  os_disk {
    caching              = "ReadWrite"
    storage_account_type = "Standard_LRS"
  }

  source_image_reference {
    publisher = "MicrosoftWindowsServer"
    offer     = "WindowsServer"
    sku       = "2016-Datacenter"
    version   = "latest"
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you share your terraform script?

Comment: @AllenWu: Thank you for your help. I have attached the terraform with the original post. Nothing fancy. Just a sample code from the internet that I am using to learn terraform.

Answer (score 0):

Combined with your another post, the step 4 cannot be achieved, so you get this error.

A tenant can have multiple subscriptions, but a subscription can only be tied to a tenant.

You mistakenly thought that you successfully gave the service principal named "example-app" (from another tenant) Contributor access to the subscription because there is a service principal with the same name in this subscription.

So your design cannot be implemented.